# How to, from a CLI program like crudini, edit an config file like /etc/os-release and /etc/lsb-release?

Tags: configuration-management

Example:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="UniOS 20.04.1 2021.05.15 LTS customized using Cubic on 2021-05-15 21:31"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

What I want to change:

```
UniOS 20.04.1 2021.05.15 LTS customized using Cubic on 2021-05-15 21:31
```

I don't want to use a text editor, but an CLI program like crudini that accepts a command to directly do that on config files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply use `sed` on the file. It searches for one string and replaces it with another string. Lots of examples here in **Ask Ubuntu** and all over the internet.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, this would require to guess how it is "UniOS 20.04.1 2021.05.15 LTS customized using Cubic on 2021-05-15 21:31" instead of directly pointing into PRETTY_NAME

Comment: I'm not an expert on `sed` but I think it can match on `PRETTY_NAME` and then replace whats behind it in double quotes (`"`). Sorry I missed that inference in the first place though. This should work for you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66878/how-can-i-replace-text-after-a-specific-word-using-sed/599088

Comment: Ok, it worked; thanks. But still it didn't answered this question.

Comment: *"You can't always get what you want, but if you try sometimes, you can get what you need"*